# Should the area in which you received your master's degree be capitalized?

Tags: capitalization

For my resume, I have a summary at the top that starts with "Dedicated individual with Master of Science in biomedical engineering." Should "biomedical engineering" be capitalized? Should "Master of Science" be capitalized?

(This is for a project, I'm not actually a biomedical engineer.)

Comment: There are no express rules. There is no right or wrong here, so there is no "should / should not be capitalised." By 'capitalised', I assume you mean *initial* capitals - not *all* capitals? Personally I would suggest capitalising **both** phases or neither. In this case probably both - but primarily because you want them to stand out, rather than for any grammatical reasons.

Comment: Yes, I meant the first letters of them. I think I will do both, so that it looks better.

Comment: Related question: [Should “Applied Cryptography” be capitalized? Is it a proper noun?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/117144/should-applied-cryptography-be-capitalized-is-it-a-proper-noun/117145#117145)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about a Master's degree, it should be capitalized as a proper noun. Similarly, if the name of the course (and the title on your degree certificate) was 'Biomedical Engineering*, then capitalise it to show the fact. Small letters in the latter case might mean "Well, the course title was 'Capillary Valving' but I specialised in biomedical engineering."

And if you say "I am - a master of science!" you should probably add "Bwahahaha!"so that everyone knows that you are a mad scientist.