# Capitalization of field when mentioning a degree?

Tags: capitalization

Is this proper usage and capitalization?

> University of Calgary graduate in Bachelor of Science, Chemical Engineering.

or

> University of Calgary graduate in Bachelor of Science, chemical engineering.

Another one:

> University of Calgary graduate in Bachelor of Science, Chemical Engineering with energy and environment specialization.

or

> University of Calgary graduate in Bachelor of Science, Chemical Engineering with Energy and Environment Specialization.

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[Capitalize fields of study?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6246)*. Also see *[Should "Applied Cryptography" be capitalized? Is it a proper noun?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/117144/should-applied-cryptography-be-capitalized-is-it-a-proper-noun)* and *[Should the area in which you received your master's degree be capitalized?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/117426)*

Answer (score 0):

Capitalization rules vary slightly between style guides. I use THE CHICAGO MANUAL OF STYLE. I would reword a little bit, but here you go:

"A University of Calgary graduate with a Bachelor of Science from the Department of Chemical Engineering with specialization in energy and environmental applications"

You can abbreviate "Bachelor of Science" to B.S. (no space). If you exclude "Department" then "chemical engineering" would be lower case and look awkward.

The way you have it worded, you could say "A B.S. degree in chemical engineering from the University of Calgary with specialization in environment and energy"