# Capitals in research areas and names of theories etc in mathematics?

Tags: nouns, capitalization, mathematics

Consider areas in Mathematics such as Percolation Theory, Reliability Engineering, Reliability Theory, Theoretical Physics, Theoretical Computer Science, Algebraic Geometry — do I write the names with a capital letter or with small letters?

Comment: You can do either one, but be consistent. (And proper names like Banach in Banach spaces should be capitalized regardless.)

Comment: I'd say with small letters (as Wikipedia does, unless proper names are involved), but note that sometimes these are names of university departments or groups, and then you'd use capitals.

Comment: Also see *[Should “Applied Cryptography” be capitalized? Is it a proper noun?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/117144)* and *[Should the area in which you received your master's degree be capitalized?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/117426)* among others.

Answer (score 0):

Capitalising mathematical nouns are puzzling because you need to know whether some noun is a proper noun such as Hilbert or Banach. Also, some institutional names, degree names and course names are capitalised even though the nouns generally not.

**1. Area names with proper nouns such as author names or people names with capital**

> **B**ayesian theory, **B**oolean algebra, **B**anach spaces, **H**ilbert spaces -- where the first word is actually a proper name of a person so hence capital

and in comparison the following are not proper nouns

> percolation theory, algebraic geometry, theoretical physics -- small letter because no name in the names

**2. Degree names in capital**

> Master degree is a proper noun so hence it should be capitalised, instructed in [Should the area in which you received your master's degree be capitalized?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/117426), so Master of Science in Operations Research or Master of Science in Philosophy are all capitalised.

**3. Official names of courses are capitalised such as Linear Algebra Course I**

> Example demonstrated with cryptography courses in [Should "Applied Cryptography" be capitalized? Is it a proper noun?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/117144/should-applied-cryptography-be-capitalized-is-it-a-proper-noun)