# capital case within a text

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

When I write a sentence like the one below in a text, the start of each word should be capital or just the first one? Which one of the following sentences is correct? if both of them are correct then which one is recommended?

I learned about **Inverse kinematics**

or

I learned about **Inverse Kinematics**

and what about

I learned about **Physically based rendering**

or

I learned about **Physically Based Rendering**

Comment: Also see *[Capitalize fields of study?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/624)* and *[Should “Applied Cryptography” be capitalized? Is it a proper noun?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/117144)* among others.

Answer (score 0):

Neither is correct.

> I learned about inverse kinematics.

Is correct, both words should be written in lowercase.

Inverse kinematics (*I* capitalized here as it is the start of a sentence) is a mathematical process, it's a similar class of thing as... algebra. We wouldn't capitalize algebra in the middle of a sentence for the same reason.

You can see some example sentences over on the Wikipedia entry:

***[Inverse kinematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_kinematics)*** (Wikipedia)

> Inverse kinematics is the mathematical process of recovering the
>   movements of an object in the world from some other data, such as a
>   film of those movements, or a film of the world as seen by a camera
>   which is itself making those movements. This is useful in robotics and
>   in film animation.
>
> In robotics, inverse kinematics makes use of the kinematics equations
>   to determine the joint parameters that provide a desired position for
>   each of the robot's end-effectors. Specification of the movement of
>   a robot so that its end-effectors achieve the desired tasks is known
>   as motion planning. Inverse kinematics transforms the motion plan into
>   joint actuator trajectories for the robot.

***Edit:***

A recent edit to the question asks about *physically based rendering*.

The same rule applies as above, all lower case in the middle of a sentence.

Physically based rendering, appears to have an accepted abbreviation (PBR).
You could refer to the model as *PBR* once you have introduced it. For example:

> "Physically based rendering (PBR) is a model in computer graphics...
>   PBR is often characterized by..." etc.

See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physically_based_rendering) for more examples of physically based rendering being used in sentences.

Comment: what about "Physically based rendering", it should be "Physically based rendering" or "Physically Based Rendering"

Comment: Same rule applies lower case in the middle of a sentence. Physically based rendering, appears to have an accepted abbreviation (PBR) so you could refer to it as PBR once you have introduced it. For example... "Physically based rendering (PBR) is a model in computer graphics... PBR is often characterized by..." etc. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physically_based_rendering

Comment: so "Physically Based Rendering" is totally wrong? I should write "Physically based rendering" when the first time it appears in the text.

Comment: Yes capitalizing each word is wrong. No you should write "physically based rendering" the first time it appears in a text, unless it is starting a sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Only [proper nouns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_noun) within a sentence should be capitalized.

Proper nouns exclusively refer to unique entities within a class, such as specific people or places. For example, the park would not be capitalized, but Hype Park would. A group of ministers is lower case, but the Minister is uppercase.

As inverse kinematics is not a unique entity, it should not be captialized.